# HTML email sent via PHPMailer says it sends but it's never received

Tags: php, phpmailer, html-email

I have been working on this problem for a week now. We have a PHP program where a user enters a start and end date, and the program calculates how much time to spend on each step to complete the assignment by the due date. Right now the program just creates a php webpage with the steps and dates, but I want to give users the option to email these results to themselves.

I'm using PHPMailer and have finally managed to create an html template and have php variables passed into it when the user submits their email. I know this part is working because I display the $body message on the page after submission and everything looks good. The problem is that now I'm not receiving the actual email, even though I get a message on the page saying it was sent. They are not in my junk mail and I've tried sending to my work email, yahoo, gmail, etc. with no luck on any of them.

During this week of trial and error, I would receive the email, however it would be empty, or the php variables would not come through. Now I'm no longer receiving the email at all (despite a success message), however the print $message; displays perfectly with all variables included as one would hope.

Can anyone help me please?

**HTML email template:**

```
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body>
<b>Starting Assignment:</b> %date1%<br>
<b>Assignment Due:</b> %date2%<br>
<b>You have %days% days to finish this assignment.</b>
<br><br>
<h1>Step 1</h1>
<b>By %step1%:</b> <i>Get started </i><br>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://ahelpfulwebsite' target='_blank'>Understand the Assignment</a></li>
</ul>
</body></html>
```

**My Mailer:**

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';


if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
$mail = new PHPMailer; 
//get user imput   
$email = $_POST['email'];
$date1 = $_POST['date1'];
$date2 = $_POST['date2'];
$days = $_POST['days'];
$time1 = $_POST['time1'];
$time2 = $_POST['time2'];
$time= abs($time1-$time2);
$days = (int)$days;

$format= "l M d, Y";
$stage1 = $time1;
$stage1 += ($time * .03);   
$step1 = date($format, $stage1);

$message = file_get_contents('textonly.html'); 
$message = str_replace('%date1%', $date1, $message); 
$message = str_replace('%date2%', $date2, $message); 
$message = str_replace('%days%', $days, $message);
$message = str_replace('%step1%', $step1, $message); 

$mail->setFrom('email@myemail.com');
$mail->addReplyTo('email@myemail.com');
$mail->addAddress($email);
$mail->Subject  = 'Assignment Checklist';
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet='utf-8';
$mail->WordWrap = 70;  
}

if(!$mail->send()) {
  print 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
 print 'Your email has been sent.';
}

print "<br><br>";
print $message;
?>
```

Comment: It's possible there aren't any issues with your code, but your email provider (for ex: Gmail) blacklisted you because your sender email domain is different from the domain of the website. I can recommend you to use mailcatcher to be sure your email has sent or not.

Comment: I wondered if that could be an issue. I'll check out Mailcatcher. Thanks.

Comment: You're sending via the `mail()` function (which PHPMailer uses by default), which means you're sending through a local mail server - check its logs. This kind of thing is covered in the PHPMailer docs - should be the first place you look.